# Configuring Traefik ForwardAuth middleware with Keycloak for Docker Swarm service authentication

Tags: keycloak, docker-swarm, traefik

I have a Docker Swarm setup where I want to restrict access to a specific service, named ttyd. Traefik provides a useful middleware called ForwardAuth that allows routing traffic to a URL and authenticating the response at that URL.

I'm interested in using Keycloak for authentication, but I'm having trouble determining which endpoint URL from the "Endpoints OpenID Endpoint Configuration" to use. I also need to know how to configure the client to define the URL where the ttyd service is hosted.

How can I configure Traefik's ForwardAuth middleware with Keycloak to authenticate access to my Docker Swarm service?

I have successfully added a middleware "keycloak-auth" in the dynamic traefik file and registered it to my service. Only setting up the correct url to add redirect and client id is missing.